# Django. Check `unique_together` only if both Model fields were provided for create and update calls

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I need to check `unique_together` only in case both fields were supplied to admin creation `Form` or via `API` request for both `create` and `update` calls. In case this happens and fields are not `unique_together` I need to propagate `Exception` to `django-admin` creation `Form` and `RestFramework`'s `Serializer/ViewSet`.

Here's a simplified example of my model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    time = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    some_other_field = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ...
```

As you can see at the level of model both `time` and `date` are not required and are nullable.

Application logic on the other hand requires at least one of those fields to be provided and if both are supplied – this pair should be unique for entire table to avoid duplication of `datetime` composition.

This model is accessed through these nodes: `django-admin` and `DjangoRestFramework`'s endpoint using `ViewSet`.

Creation of new record does not seem to be a problem from `API` perspective, I can override `validate` method of `Serializer`:

```
    def validate(self, data):
    if not data.get('time') and not data.get('date'):
        raise serializers.ValidationError(
            "At least one of this fields is required: time, date"
        )

    if OpenTable.objects.filter(
            time=data.get('time'),
            date=data.get('date')).exists():
        raise serializers.ValidationError('Duplicates for date or datetime not allowed')
    return data
```

But this becomes a problem when I receive `PUT` or `PATCH` request, because then despite this record being the only one in table I raise `ValidationError` precisely because there is a record with this `date`-`time` pair.

Overriding `validate` method also does not solve problem of preventing creation of such a pair from `Django-Admin`.

At the moment the closest I got to validating this is using `save` method of `MyModel`, but I can't understand how exactly to handle this case there to comply with `create`/`update` flow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Django Rest Framework validation, you can use self.instance check to use different validation flows for creation and modification of an object;

```
def validate(self, data):
    if self.instance:
        # Modifiying an existing instance, run validations accordingly
    else:
        # Creading a new instance, run validations accordingly
```

As for admin site, you can use Django's **ModelForm** structure and their validations to enforce validtion for admin site. You'll need to set you admin site to use your custom form for **MyModel**

Comment: Is there any way to differ `PUT` and `PATCH` calls in `validate` or any other method of Serializer?

Comment: @StanRedoute you can use self.context.get('request') in serializer to get the request, and most probably get request method through the request object. Be careful with this though, request may not always be set in serializer context, if you initialize the serializer in python console for instance.